# Square root of a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> How can I find the square root of the following non-diagonalisable matrix?
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix}
>   5 & -1 \\
>   4 & 1
>  \end{pmatrix}$$

I have shown that

$$A^{n}=3^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}
  2n+3 & -n \\
  4n & 3-2n
 \end{pmatrix}$$

though I'm not sure how to use this fact.

Comment: Have you tried considering an arbitrary matrix whose square is your matrix? That would give you four equations, with four unknowns, which you might be able to solve.

Comment: @Moo: That one is symmetric, which changes everything. This one, also, has a double eigenvalue, which complicates things.

Comment: @AlexM.: Thanks - didn't pay enough attention, but my first comment and that paper stand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct computation starting with an arbitrary matrix $A$ with $A^2$ equal to the above matrix yields $4$ quadratic equations in $4$ variables, and we obtain
$$
A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{pmatrix} 4 & -\frac{1}{2} \cr 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Of course, also $-A$ is a solutions.

Remark: In fact, we may reduce the system of equations to only two equations
$$
b^2-4a^2+20=0,\quad b^2-2ab+4=0.
$$

Comment: The truly remarkable fact is that the general formula that the OP has found for $A^n$ also works for $n = \frac 1 2$ and probably many other non-natural values. How to explain this? It is like some sort of analytic continuation, but how exactly? Functional calculus?

Comment: Using your method you end up with the equations: $a^2+bc=5, d^2+bc=1, c(a+d)=4$ and $b(a+d)=-1$. How do you solve these equations though, I just get lost in a slog of algebra.

Comment: @MadChickenMan Assume, say, $c\neq 0$ and substitute $b=(5-a^2)/c$ and $d=(4-ac)/c$. The remaining equations are easy.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I believe that the map $z \mapsto A^z$ may be defined for "most" $z \in \Bbb C$, and then some identity theorem for matrix-valued holomorphic maps should guarantee its equality to the formula obtained by the OP (one problem being that the only accumulation point for $\Bbb N \subset \Bbb C$ is $\infty$ on the Riemann sphere - and I do not know of any identity theorem for such a situation).

Answer (score 1):

In general if $A$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix conjugated to $B=c (I + N)$ with $c>0$ and $N$ nilpotent (i.e. $N^2=0$) then $A^p$ is conjugated to $B^p=c^p(I+pN)$ for any real value of $p$. You may check this for integer $p$, which extends to rational and then  to real (and with some care, to complex numbers) by completion.

So all you need is to rewrite your matrix in Jordan form
and take the square root of the Jordan form:

In our case you may pick  $P=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 &1 \end{matrix}\right)$ (the first vector is in the kernel of $A-3I$, the other is in the kernel of $(A-eI)^2=0$, whence arbitrary in the present case). Then
$$ A P = P 
\left(\begin{matrix} 3 & 3 \\ 0 &3 \end{matrix}\right)= PB=P \times 3  (I+ N), \ \  \mbox{with} \ \ 
N=\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 &0 \end{matrix}\right).
$$
Then:
 $$ B^{1/2} = \sqrt{3} \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$$
This happens to yield
$$ A^{1/2}= P B^{1/2} P^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \left(\begin{matrix} 4 & \frac{-1}{2}\\ 2 & 2\end{matrix}\right).$$
In our 2 by 2 case the solution is unique up to sign. For general complex exponent (we need a cut in the complex plane), $z\in {\Bbb C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$:

$$ A^{z}= P B^{z} P^{-1} = 3^z   \left( \begin{matrix} 1 +\frac{2}{3}z& -\frac{1}{3}z\\ \frac{4}{3}z & 1-\frac{2}{3}z\end{matrix}\right) 
 .$$

Comment: Since you are saying "in general", you may want to clarify that what you are saying applies to $2\times2$ matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The Jordan decomposition $A=SJS^{-1}$ is given by the matrices $$S = \begin{pmatrix}1&\frac12\\2&0 \end{pmatrix},\quad J = \begin{pmatrix}3&1\\0&3 \end{pmatrix}. $$
Let $\lambda = 3$ and write $J = \lambda (I+K)$, where $$K=\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac13\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Using the Mercator series, we compute the logarithm of $J$:
\begin{align}
\log J &= \log(\lambda(I+K))\\
&= \log(\lambda I) + \log (I+K)\\
&= 0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{K^n}n\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}0&\log\frac43\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Write $J=S^{-1}AS$, then we have
\begin{align}
\log A &= S(\log J) S^{-1}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}1&\frac12\\2&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&\log\frac43\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac12\\2&-1 \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}\frac23+\log 3&-\frac13\\\frac43&-\frac23+\log3 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
It follows that
$$A^{\frac12} = e^{\log\left(A^{\frac12}\right)}
= e^{\frac12\log A}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{pmatrix} 4 & -\frac{1}{2} \cr 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

By the way, there is a very similar formula for power of $\log A$:

$$(\log A)^n = \frac13(\log 3)^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}2n+3\log 3& -n\\ 4n& -2n+3\log 3 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: Very nice(+1)..