# How many different square roots can you find of this $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: matrices

> A matrix B is said to be a square root of a matrix A if $BB=A$
>
> How many different square roots can you find of
>
> $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 5&0\\0&9\end{pmatrix}.$$

When attempting to answer this question i've set $B=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ and found the equations to solve,
$$a^2+bc=5$$$$ab+bd=0$$$$ca+cd=0$$$$cb+d^2=9$$
Not too sure how to solve from here, $$5-a^2=bc=9-d^2$$ Solving this,
$$d^2-a^2=4$$

Comment: $d^2 - a^2 = 4$ does not implies that $d-a = 2$.  Or have I misunderstood your process?

Comment: Often when you have an expression equal to $0$, it is often helpful to factorise it. Your middle two expressions simplify to $b(a+d)=c(a+d)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: If $d+a \neq 0$ then $b=0$, $c=0$, $a^2=5$, and $d^2=9$. Compare the first and last equation. Can $d=-a$?

Comment: If $d=-a$ then $bc=?$ Use $a^2+bc=5$ and $d^2+bc=9$.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done. The first and last equation gives $d^2-a^2=4$, which you have already noted. Hence $4=d^2-a^2=(d-a)(d+a)$, so that $d+a\neq 0$. Then the second and third equation gives $b=c=0$ and you are done.

Your approach also works fine for matrices which are not diagonalisable:
[Square root of a $2 \times 2$ matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958333/square-root-of-a-2-times-2-matrix?rq=1).